# Is "accomplishment" an abstract noun?

Tags: abstract-nouns

My class has been taught about concrete and abstract noun. This concept already seems self-explanatory (abstract has no physical existence and can't be experienced whereas concrete nouns are the opposite). Two days ago I thought that the word "accomplishment" was an abstract since it is something that we give value to but then my teacher said that it was a concrete noun since things like paintings are concrete things.

After checking the definition of "accomplishment" I realized that it could be both concrete and abstract such as the accomplishment of reducing inflation (abstract) or something physical like a metal.

Can somebody clarify what type of noun "accomplishment" is?

Comment: Winging it here, your teacher's position is that an abstract label to things that **can be** concrete things makes the label concrete. Not much point in arguing with such concrete/leaden/stubborn thinking.

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said. Your teacher is [obviously incompetent,](https://homework.study.com/explanation/what-is-the-abstract-noun-for-fail.html) and should look for a different job.

Comment: ...and if you got the idea that *abstract has no physical existence and can't be experienced*, you seriously need to ***unlearn*** that nonsense. ***Happiness*** is a typical abstract noun, and hopefully everyone is capable of experiencing *that* at least sometimes! An "abstract noun" means *something **physical / tangible*** - often described as *something you can **touch***. Bear in mind that ***star,*** for example, is a "concrete noun" *because it has physical existence*, but obviously you can't "touch" even the nearest star (our sun).

Comment: Anything that can't be touched (in terms of nouns like this) is usually abtract. And concrete is basically physical or made of matter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "An 'abstract noun' means something physical"—oops, was that the opposite?

Comment: @AndyBonner: Ooops! Lost a negation somewhere there! But hopefully the OP gets my substantial point - that "concrete / abstract" doesn't differentiate things that *can* be "experienced" from things that *can't*. And that when we say concrete nouns refer to "tangible" things, that includes everything that has physical existence, not just "nearby" things that we can actually *touch*.

Comment: On ELU, there is a thread in which the whole notion of a clear distinction between 'concrete' and 'abstract' was challenged, with references to heavyweight psychosemanticists thinking the usual ideas are far too imprecise. Can a hole be perceived by the senses? How should the noun be classified?  Does [abbreviating](https://teachnthrive.com/history-passages/world-history-passages/the-achievements-of-ancient-egypt/) [Teach 'n' Thrive] ...

Comment: 'The building of the pyramids is perhaps the most famous of all ancient Egyptian achievements' to 'The pyramids are perhaps the most famous of all ancient Egyptian achievements' change the status of 'achievements'?

Comment: That was my bad again. I didn't convey what really happened. I do know abstract things can take a concrete existence, but the abstract thing in is purest definition form just can't. In other words, my teacher did tell us abstract things can take physical forms, but you can't do things like drink sadness or directly measure it. My bad again

Answer (score 6):

Although a tangible object such as a piece of art may be called *an accomplishment*, that does not mean that 'accomplishment' is in itself a tangible thing. In the same way, a physical deed may be described as "*an act of loyalty*", or "*an act of love*", yet love and loyalty are human traits and prime examples of abstract nouns.

Whether something is an *accomplishment* or not will often be relative and maybe even opinion-based. For example, you might be impressed by something that does not impress someone else, so you may consider it an accomplishment but the other person doesn't. This shows that the accomplishment itself is abstract. Also, someone may say that an entirely intangible act, such as conquering a negative personality trait, is an accomplishment.

Comment: I kind of get it, but the google definition calls anything an accomplishment so long as it has been completed successfully, so I thought anything physical that was completed successfully would count. In the context the word accomplishment came from, (I forgot to include this earlier), it took an objective stance. Here was the original sentence : The people felt a sense of pride in their accomplishment. I was wondering whether or not accomplishment would be abstract in that context. I also don't entirely get the an accomplishment being physical while accomplishment itself is still intangible.

Comment: @Agio392 This is getting more philosophical than linguistic. I'm repeating what is in my answer here, but calling something 'an accomplishment' is not really so different to saying something is good, great, wonderful etc. If you can't see it, touch it, or measure it by some immovable, agreed scale then it is abstract. You can have a 'sense of accomplishment' and nobody but you will sense it. You could share an accomplishment with somebody else, yet both judge your own work differently. It's not tangible. It's a concept. It's abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it.

There are some categories of words that are important because they are part of the grammar of English.  For example regular and irregular verbs (you need to know how to form the past tense of verbs)

But the categories of abstract and concrete nouns are not part of the grammar of English.  They are part of the meaning of words.

So consider that some nouns mean "types of animal" and some nouns are not "types of animal".  You might ask is "cat" an animal noun?  Yes, it is, usually, but sometimes it means a type of whip (not an animal).  Is "man" an animal noun?  Is "bee" an animal noun?  Is "amoeba"? Is "robot"? Is "pork"?  Is "lamb"?

With meanings there are always grey areas. There are always words with multiple meanings and words with meanings that are too fuzzy. Nobody would claim that every noun can be completely categorised as an animal noun or non-animal noun.  So why expect that every word can be completely categorised as a concrete noun or an abstract noun.

Normally "accomplishment" is not an animal noun and not a concrete noun. In some situations it's meaning might shade into a concrete sense, but this isn't it's main meaning.

Comment: Actually, it is extremely important since abstract nouns don't need determiners. Happiness is infectious. Wealth can be a good thing.

Comment: No.  This is a misconception.  Uncountable nouns don't need determiners. And uncountable nouns can refer to both concrete and abstract things.  "Rice is delicious" uses a concrete noun "rice".